# How to get a pipeline run error with Azure runs REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using Azure's Runs API to get a pipeline run result as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#runresult

I can see in the documentation how to get the state and final result so I can know if the run was a success or a failure. However, in case of a failure, I don't see how I can get the error that occurred in that run as a string.

How can I get the actual error which caused the pipeline run to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the REST API "[**Timeline - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to list the issues (error and warning) associated with a run.

**Note:**
This API can only list the first 10 issues. If the run has more than 10 issues, the rest will not be listed in the response. To get the complete issues, you can use the API "[**Builds - Get Build Log**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" or "[**Logs - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/logs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to get the complete logs that contains the complete issues.

**[UPDATE]**

The **`buildId`** is same as the **`runId`**, and you can find it from the URL of the pipeline (build) run.

The **`timelineId`** is not required in the API request, you can use the request URI like as below.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline/?api-version=6.0
```

Comment: I actually already tried the logs part on a pipeline with an error. All it gave me was some json list with no useful information at all

Comment: Also, how can I get a build id or a timeline id through the code? I'm invoking the REST command to run the pipeline and it doesn't return this information

Comment: Hi @YonatanNir, I have updated my answer with more details. Please check it.

Comment: It seems like that the request in the update is the best option is it gives me a list of objects with the issues which is easy to parse. The "Get build log" is also working but is giving me the entire log and I need to start parsing things without knowing how they should appear. And like I said before - the "Logs - Get" doesn't work at all as it has no meaningful info. I accepted the answer but you should think about removing the logs-get part